# WebStorm not showing .vue syntax highlighting on on file but is on another

Tags: vue.js, webstorm

Does anyone know what is causing this problem? I can't seem to figure it out.

When I create a new `.vue` file, I can't get any autocomplete/syntax highlight at all.

But the one I created at the start of the project seems to work fine.

[image: WebStorm .vue syntax error]

Comment: Don't you need to actually select the language you want to have an highlight on? Somewhere on the bottom or via a command palette?

Comment: Webstorm knows it via File Type in the settings (*.vue). Thats why you see the synxtax highlights with the file on the left. But not sure why the file on the right doesn't have it.

Comment: You will probably need to share some of your IDE settings here tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as if the file `GameDetails.vue` is treated as plain text file. Does the issue persist if you rename the file? Please check the registered patterns in **Settings | Editor | File types**, **Text** and **Auto-detect file type by content** file types - can you see `GameDetails.vue` or any pattern with `.vue` suffix there? Removing it from the list should solve the problem.

Comment: I reinstalled webstorm and it fixes itself. Not sure what happened. I didn't touch any of the settings either.